# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager while making apk in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

`Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager. I use react native Expo. This Error came when APK is build and I run Command npx react-native log-android.Then The App is crashing and Sometimes white screen is rendering

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {View} from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from './firebase';

import Navigator from "./path";
import { GestureDetector, Gesture } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const App = () => {
const native = Gesture.Native();

return (
<GestureDetector gesture={native}>
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
<NavigationContainer>
<Navigator/>
</NavigationContainer>
</View>
</GestureDetector>
);
};

export default App;
```

path.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from './components/Login';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import Maps from './components/Maps';
import History from "./components/History";
import OnboardingScreen from './components/OnboardingScreen';
import MapComponent from './components/MapComponent';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'; // Import AsyncStorage from the correct package
export default function Stacky() {
const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = useState(null);
let routeName;

useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then((value) => {
    if (value === null) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched', 'true'); // No need to wait for setItem to finish, although you might want to handle errors
        setIsFirstLaunch(true);
     } else {
    setIsFirstLaunch(false);
    }
    }).catch(error => console.error('AsyncStorage getItem error:', error));
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) {
      setInitializing(false);
     }
});

    return unsubscribe;

}, []);

if (isFirstLaunch === null) {
   return null;
} else if (isFirstLaunch) {
    routeName = 'Login';
} else {
   routeName = user ? 'Maps' : 'Login';
}

if (initializing) {
   return null;
}
return (
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName={routeName}\>
    <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={OnboardingScreen} \>
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} \>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} \>
    <Stack.Screen name="History" component={History} \>
    <Stack.Screen name="Maps" component={Maps} \>
    <Stack.Screen name="MapComponent" component={MapComponent} \>
</Stack.Navigator>
);
}
```

White Screen is rendering.`

Comment: show me your package..json